# img src from php file

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Image uploader</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Image uploader</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Before Image:
<input type="file" name="before"  size="40">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000">
<br />
<?php echo '<img src="showimage.php?type=before"/>' ?>

<br />
<br />

After Image:
<input type="file" name="after"  size="40">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000">
<br />
<?php echo '<img src="showimage.php?type=after"/>' ?>

<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Here's my showimage:

```
<?php
   if((is_uploaded_file($_FILES['before']['tmp_name']) && getimagesize($_FILES['before']['tmp_name']) != false) || 
      (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['after']['tmp_name']) && getimagesize($_FILES['after']['tmp_name']) != false))
    {
            header("Content-type: image/jpg");
            if ($_GET['type'] == 'before')
                echo $before_img = fopen($_FILES['before']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
            else ($_GET['type'] == 'after')
                echo $after_img = fopen($_FILES['after']['tmp_name'], 'rb');

    }
   else {
          echo 'http://www.stampinup.net/esuite/images/pages/noImageUploaded.png?763.458';
   }

?>
```

The issue is that img src won't render the showimage.php.. why is this?

Comment: This is a continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068880/showing-image-loaded-from-file-before-upload-post, but isn't quite a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a fundamental misunderstanding of PHP file uploads and file handling in general.

`echo $somevar = fopen` won't output the image itself. It'll put the handle that fopen returns, which'll be some meaningless integer. What you want is (at minimum):

```
readfile($_FILES['before']['tmp_name']);
```

which'll open the file and send its contents to the browser.

You are also not saving the uploaded files anywhere, so basically the user uploads 2 images, you output one, and then the images are deleted - PHP does not save uploaded files permanently. You must manually move/copy the files elsewhere in order to preserve them. Generally that's done with the [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) function

As well, referring to your upload handler script in an `<img>` tag will also not work. That call will go out as a GET request, and file uploads do NOT occur via GET, so your script will return an empty/broken image because there is no file for it to read.

Comment: so what is the fix to this? I need to save the two uploaded files first using move_uploaded_file?

Comment: Yes, and only after you've moved them somewhere in your document root can you use them as targets of an `<img src="...">` reference.

Comment: move_uploaded_file() will store the image permanently? the issue is that I just want to show this image temporarily.. it's going to be used for cropping later on

Comment: yes, unless you move the file somewhere where the OS might clean it up (e.g. /tmp).

Comment: all I want to do is just show the image that the user has picked from their computer... how do I do that?

Comment: In other words, you've duplicate your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068880/showing-image-loaded-from-file-before-upload-post

Comment: I need to see some code as I don't understand what someone has suggested on that page

Comment: also I think what you're saying is that $_FILES['before']['tmp_name'] won't be passed in the GET request? so I'd have to save this somewhere and the uploader script will just spit out the image from the saved file?